# How to make less than or greater than comparison in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Please anybody explain how to do below check in angularjs

```
<div ng-show="{{offset <= 10}}">Show Me</div>
```

If i run it like this it breaks the html, i think due to "<" than in comparison

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Don't use `{{}}`s:

```
<div ng-show="offset <= 10">Show Me</div>
```

The expression given to ng-show is evaluated against the current scope, so there is no need for interpolation – the `{{}}`s.

You would need the `{{}}`s if you wanted to do something like this:

```
<div>Offset is <= 10: {{offset <= 10}}</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this, it works!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
  </script>
 <body>
  <div  ng-app="">
    10&lt;20 : {{10&lt;20}}
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
{{ data[0].Insight_Value_2 <= 15 ?data[0].Insight_Value_2 : data[0].Insight_Value_2/2 }}
```

It works.