# How to use ">" comparator in AngularJS ng-if statement

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ng-if

Is it possible to use the 'greater than' comparator in an ng-if in HTML?
The problem is that the ">" symbol prematurely closes the HTML tag.

ex.
this: `<div ng-if="foo>0" class="bar"> (HTML STUFF) </div>`

is read as: `<div ng-if="foo"> (0 class="bar"> HTML STUFF) </div>`

I ended up getting around this by using ng-if="foo!=0" but I could probably use the less than comparator instead but I was just curious in case I absolutely HAD to use the greater than symbol for some reason. Or would I perhaps have to move this logic somewhere else like in my controller instead of in my view?

**EDIT 1**
So it definitely seems like the comparator itself isn't the problem and something else is going on in my code. Oddly, when I have spaces before and after the comparator it works but without spaces it doesn't. I'm also using angular 1.3.15 if that means anything.

`<div class="paginate" ng-if="list.total > 0">` works

`<div class="paginate" ng-if="list.total>0">` does not work

Comment: stick your logic in a function

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403835/how-to-make-less-than-or-greater-than-comparison-in-angularjs

Comment: *"The problem is that the ">" symbol prematurely closes the HTML tag."*. No, it doesn't. Why do you think so?

Comment: Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1ZmSjz?p=preview) with a working example.

Comment: There's something else going on in your case. I've used GT/LT many times without issue.

Comment: This can also happen when you use a SVG-document. The document will not bubble any input event (may it be a hover or click event) to the parent elements. For this case you can use the CSS property `pointer-events: none;` to stop any event going inside the SVG, so default bubbling will work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an example of using the `>` symbol.  This works fine.

```
<div ng-if="myvariable.length > 2">

</div>
```

Comment: @Tenzolinho yes it does

Answer (score 5):

I recommend creating a method on the scope and abstracting the logic of the condition. The business rules may expand and change. With a separate method you don't need to alter the template.

```
// in controller
$scope.isValidFoo = function () {
    return $scope.foo > 0;
}

// in template
<div ng-if="isValidFoo()">...</div>
```