# format option text based on condition

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to format the option text based on certain condition. I have tried several ways but doesn't seem to be working. For a workaround I could use jquery and populate the option list based on condition but trying to do it without adding more code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<option value="fooditem_size1">{{selectedFoodItem.fooditem_size1_name}} 
  <span ng-if="selectedFoodItem.fooditem_size1_price > 0"> + 
       ${{selectedFoodItem.fooditem_size1_price}}
  </span>
</option>
```

Comment: It should work. Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926520 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810278

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ternary operator:

```
<option value="fooditem_size1">
    {{selectedFoodItem.fooditem_size1_name + 
        (selectedFoodItem.fooditem_size1_price > 0) ? 
          ( ' + $' + selectedFoodItem.fooditem_size1_price ) : "" }}
</option>
```

The only permitted content of an `<option>` element is text, possibly with escaped characters (like `&eacute;`).

For more information, see

- [MDN HTML Reference - `<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)